# How do I exclude a header row from getDataRange()?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to fetch the range of all cells with data in it, but not including the header row.

I found that getDataRange() captures all the cells with data in it, and to avoid including the first row, I thought I could just delete the first element in what I am assuming is an array?

How can I do this/ is there a more elegant way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 15):

- You want to retrieve the values without the 1st row using `getDataRange()`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script 1 :

In this sample, `offset()` is used. In this case, before the values are retrieved, the range is modified.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var headerRowNumber = 1;
var values = sheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRowNumber, 0, sheet.getLastRow() - headerRowNumber).getValues();
Logger.log(values)
```

#### Sample script 2 :

In this sample, `shift()` is used. In this case, after the values were retrieved, the values are modified.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
values.shift();
Logger.log(values)
```

#### References:

- [offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset-columnoffset-numrows)
- [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I think the 4 parameter version of `offset` is needed for proper multicell selection

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for your support. Yes. I missed that. When `offset(1, 0)` is used, the range of rows is shifted. So in this case, because the shift of column is `0`, it required to be `offset(1, 0, sheet.getLastRow() - 1)`. I updated my answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you can, try to use good old `getRange()` instead of `getDataRange().offset()` -- from my testing it's 2-3x faster.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the header and the rest of the values separately

```
var values=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
var header=values.splice(0,1);
Logger.log(values);
Logger.log(header);
```